# Reentrant code and local variables

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method like:

```
private static string AmpRemove(string str)
{
    int index = str.IndexOf('&');
    if (index > 0)
        str = str.Substring(0, index);
    return str;
}
```

Here I am trying to get text from a string until `&` character is found. My senior modified this method to

```
private static string AmpRemove(string str)
{
    if (str.IndexOf('&') > 0)
        str = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('&'));
    return str;
}
```

So instead of storing the `index`, it will calculate it twice, and his reasoning was that since that method would be called in multiple threads, there could be invalid value stored in `index`.

My understanding of thread is limited, but I believe each thread would have its own stack, where the parameter `str` and `index` would be pushed. I have tried reasoning with him, that this is a reentrant code and there is no way that multiple threads could modify a local variable in this method.

So, my question is, Am I right in assuming that <strike>caching</strike> storing `index` is a better solution, since it will not involve calculating index twice and since it is local variable and `str` is a parameter local to method, there is no way that multiple threads could modify/change `str` and `index` ?

Is that correct ?

Comment: yes you are right. caching `index` is the wrong wording though. `index` is just a local variable to the method, independently if you use it in a threaded environment or not.

Comment: yes, not sure how I can make a good answer for this, but yes, you are right...

Comment: Yes, your senior should get a vacation.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, thanks for the comment, I changed caching to storing.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO There is also a [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that might be a better fit for questions like this.

Comment: @asawyer, thanks, but my understanding for "Code Review" is that both option should work same, I wasn't sure if the first option is thread safe and hence if they would work same.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Just throwing out there in case you hadn't seen it before. Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`index` cannot be modified given the code, because it is a local variable, and any method called from another thread is a separate call and thus does not share local variables.

However, you do not control the `string` parameter since it gets passed in. This would make it thread unsafe... Except according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), a `string` object is immutable. You can thus assume that the `string` you get passed remains the same between calls, and is thread safe. Although you reassign the value of `str`, the parameter was not passed as a `ref` and therefore that only reassigns the local pointer, it does *not* modify the caller's variable which was passed in.

Thusly, the first code, as presented, is thread-safe. Any changes to the type being passed in or how it's passed in cannot be immediately assumed thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1, for explaining that since strings are immutable, this is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your original method is threadsafe. But:

1. Reassigning method variables can be confusing, you could just return the Substring:

   `private static string AmpRemove(string str)
   {
       var index = str.IndexOf('&');
       if (index > 0) {
           return str.Substring(0, index);
       }
       return str;
   }`
2. If the '&' is at index 0 your code will return the whole string. Is that what should happen, or should it be index >= 0?

Comment: Thanks, but yes, if the `&` is index 0, then we need the whole string.